# gcd and lcm with multiple parameters Scheme, DRracket

Tags: scheme, racket, greatest-common-divisor

```
(define (gcd a b)
  (if (= b 0)
      a
      (gcd b (remainder a b))))
```

We all know about this famous function, and I know that if I want a (gcd a b c) is (gcd a b c)= (gcd a (gcd b c)). But I need to actually see code that shows me how to implement that general fuction, cause I'm not writting lot of diferent definitions of the functions, I need just the one that include infinite parameters, the actual racket gcd and lcm fuctions already do that, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.` in the parameter list to allow it to take optional arguments, which will be in a list. If there are additional arguments, recurse.

```
(define (gcd a b . more)
  (cond ((pair? more) (gcd a (apply gcd b more))
        ((= b 0) a)
        (else (gcd b (remainder a b)))))
```

Comment: Since the empty list doesn't count as false in Racket, I think the first clause needs to be `((pair? more) (gcd a (apply gcd b more))`

Comment: @soegaard Thanks. I'm a Lisp programmer, not such much Scheme, and I forget these differences.

Answer (score 2):

So you are searching for the variadic (variable number or arguments) version of the otherwise diadic `gcd` function.

Using `gcd` you can do:

```
(define (gcd* . args)  ;; gcd over a variable number of arguments
  (foldl gcd 0 args))
```

Now, you can do:

```
(gcd* 33 121 209) ;;=> 11
```